# How do I map a database name to a server name from a data file using a hash?

Tags: perl

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file_name = "rem.txt";
open(FILE, $file_name);
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ m/(\w*Svr)\b/) {
        my $server_name;
        $server_name = $1;
        my @arr_servername = $server_name;
        print "@arr_servername\n";
        #print "$server_name\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ m/-[dD]\s*\$\{(.*?)_NAME/) {
        my $database_name;
        $database_name = $1;
        my @arr_dbname = $database_name;
        print "\n-----------------\n";
        print "@arr_dbname\n";
        print "\n----------------\n";
        #print "....$database_name\n";
    }
}
```

REM.TXT

```
ewrerfSvr      //(extracted---
 Rate=rpm 
 ID=123 
 RATE=45 
 ADDR=retriveBal 
 Grocer="-r -e ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stderr -o ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stdout -A --" 
freedonSvr 
 BALFSvr   //to be extracted 
 Rate=rpm1 
 ID=12323 
 RATE=45etf 
 ADDR=retriveBal 
 Grocer="-r -e ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stderr -o ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stdout -A --" 
freedonSvr -D ${REV_AccountBalance_NAME}"// extracted
Refer
Rate =rpm
ID =234
ADDR = calbal
Grocer="-r -e ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stderr -o ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stdout -A --" -D ${REV_MAx_NAME}"
REstSvr
Grocer="-r -e ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stderr -o ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stdout -A --" 
freedonSvr -D ${REV_MinBalance_NAME}"
```

The code above retrieves a file name and database name. I want the database name to be mapped to the server name. How shall I do this?

My output retrieves all database names separately in some order and the server name in some other order. I want to use a hash to store the database name and server name, the order must be preserved. How shall I do that?

The primary need for doing this is to identify which server uses which database.

Comment: Hello Sreeja, I see you've been participating on SO for some time. By now, you should be aware of the [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Please put some effort in [formatting your questions properly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), you cannot always rely on other people to edit your sloppiness. You ask a lot, but rarely answer - that is okay, but to help improve the usefulness of SO for everyone, you should [revisit your earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/401195#questions) and pick an answer as *accepted* by clicking the hollow check-mark ✓ to the left of any answer.

Comment: it probably takes a while for that stat to be updated. @daxim, Sreeja's lack of answers is probably explained by his profile as a "programming trainee"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
my %mapping;
...
while (<FILE>) { ....
$mapping{$server_name} = $database_name;
```

Comment: i can add a condition that if it has svr and db match(only when both)get only those...How to implement that

Comment: 1. pull my $server_name and my $database_name from if-scopes to the while-scope.

2. change the elseif to if (because there are lines that match both regexes)

3. if $server_name and $database_name are set then store them in your %mapping, and blank them afterwards